# Passing filepath in Main(string[] args) no working with space caracter

Tags: c#, winforms, arguments, program-entry-point

I am trying to get filepath with args[0] in from Main(string[] args)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {                        
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            Application.Run(new RadForm1());
        }
        else
        {                
            Application.Run(new RadForm1(args[0]));
        }
    }
```

i have problems with space character. for example, path is:

```
C:\Program Files\bt\Myfile.wasp
```

but args[0] is:

```
C:\Program
```

How can I fix this problem? please Help Me.

Comment: try to wrap the string with quotes: `"C:\Program Files\bt\myprog.exe"` see [this example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6086504/tmp/Run_Debug_Configurations_and_Play_java_-_play_-____dev_play_.png)

Comment: thank you alfshin. i am Using c# Winforms. i Dont Undrastand your Example

Comment: Next time please tag your question with the relevant tags. I thought you're using Java...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis Work For Me:

```
string s="";
int i = 0;
foreach (var arg in args)
  {
    if(i != 0)
     {
      s = s + " " + arg;
     }
    i++;                     
  }
args[0] = args[0] + s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is already mentioned in the comments, simply wrap your parameter with quotes.

If you pass `C:\Program Files\bt\Myfile.wasp` to your program, Windows will interpret this as two separated parameters and you get two args:

```
args[0] = "C:\Program"
args[1] = "Files\bt\Myfile.wasp"
```

So in order to have it as one parameter in `args[0]`, you need to pass it as one parameter. And the way to do this is wrapping it in quotes like this: `"C:\Program Files\bt\Myfile.wasp"`

Comment: Thank You.
This Work For Me:
             'string s="";
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var arg in args)
                {
                    if(i != 0)
                    {
                        s = s + " " + arg;
                    }
                    i++;                     
                }
                args[0] = args[0] + s;'